# after mice/multiple imputation, how to pool RF and SVL? (GLM works)

Tags: r, svm, random-forest, pool, r-mice

I was recently introduced to mice/multiple imputation and was able to succesfully do a mice , glm model and pool the results. This only worked for a glm though. While looking into mice I could only find pool examples that used either glm or lm, but not with other models. That is my problem.I cannot pool the results for other models such  randomForest or SVL. I get the following error messages then:

`"Error, no tidy method for objects of class randomForest.formula"`

`"Error, no tidy method for objects of class svm.formula"`

Below is an overview of the features names/classes of my data

```
data=mydata
y = binary variabele 
x1 and x2 are as.numeric
x3, x4, x5 and x6 are as.factor

NAs in both 'y' and in the predictors(x1 through x6). 
mean NA% is about 20%
```

My succesfull code for mice,glm,pool below:

```
mydata_imp <- mice(mydata, m=5, maxit=5, seed=2020)
mod_glm <- with(mydata_imp, glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x5 + x6,
         family = 'binomial', na.action=na.omit))

summary(pool(mod_glm))
```

So the above works, but
when I instead try a randomForest or svl formula, it does not work.

I can execute the model/formula:

```
mod_rf <- with(mydata_imp, randomForest(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x5 + x6,
         importance = TRUE, na.action=na.omit))
```

but when I try to pool the results:

`summary(pool(mod_rf))`
or
`varImp(pool(mod_rf))`

Then i get the errors mentioned before ("no tidy method for objects of class rf")
The same for an svl model for example.

I hope this community can help me out.
fwiw: I really want to do mice and pool the results. So no stacking for example.
I did a lot of research and trial/error. Below are the main sources i used:

https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/workflow.html

https://bookdown.org/mwheymans/bookmi/data-analysis-after-multiple-imputation.html

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228553/perform-random-forest-after-multiple-imputation-with-mice

(I couldnt open the links in the stackexchange post unfortunately)

My R version is 4.0.1 (and I cannot/may not change it)

**EDIT:
ADDITIONAL INFO:**
A reply to user20650:

Thanks for your reply/hint @user20650. I did some more research after your comments. This is indeed true."The function pool() works for any object having both coef() and vcov() methods. The function tests for this, and aborts if it fails to find an appropriate method."Source: article by vanBuuren: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v045i03
https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v045i03
page 48.
You can find which methods vcov/coef have by typing in r `methods(vcov)` and
 `methods(coef)`. I did but unfortunately svm and randomForest are not in both lists(svm is in coef, but not in vcov). So it cant work that way. It also says this though:
"In addition, the pool() function will also work for objects of class lme defined in the package nlme. It is possible to pool the fixed coefficients from a linear mixed model according to Rubin’s rules.: I tried nlme using "Usage" as guide (see this link, on top: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/nlme/versions/3.1-148/topics/nlme)
 `Error in as.data.frame.deafult(data) : cannot coerce class '"mids"' to a data.frame.` The last option the article mentions is that pool can also work with class 'lme'. I looked up this class, but it would not work either, it is not meant to deal with a mids class either. The following code also did not work:
`lmer_pool(mod_rf)`
`" Error in UseMethod (" isREML" ) no applicable method for 'isREML' is applied to an object of class "c("mira", "matrix")"`. It keeps coming back mod_rf is not the correct class. I cannot seem to be able to change the class, or be able to change my method of mod_rf that it becomes the correct class.
I also looked at all questions in stackoverflow with tag 'mice' but could not find an answer either. I really am lost. I hope somebody can help. Or if its not possible, thats also okayi guess, i will do a more simple imputation. I just would want to know. Cheers

Comment: I think to pool results the model must have a covariance matrix on the parameters. Does randomForest or svm models return this?

Comment: I replied as answer to your comment (because I did not have enough characters available)

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you are trying with mixed-effects models (lme/lmer) -- it is not surprising that they can be used as the coefficents do have a var-cov matrix -- I don't see how this related to random forests of svm ?. Are you just trying to apply the lme pool method to your random -forest model ; if so this wont work as the model function return different objects. The crossvalidated link from your question suggets a way to proceed --> pool predictions.

Comment: Yes correct, I am not particially interested in lme/lmer. I was just trying out everything I could find during my research to pool the results from my rf and svm formulas on an imputed dataset. I am quite new to R btw. I tried all the answers provided in that stack stackoverflow link with my data, but I kept getting errors and couldnt make it work.The links provided there also did not work(' github page doesnt exist '). I was hoping somebody could push me in the right direction with my specific own code using the small amount of features I have here.

Comment: The selected answer I could follow at first, but then he said this: " Then you can pool the results by majority voting or averaging, depending on your dataset. You can also group the 5 imputations together and train the learner with the combined dataset. Both methods are suboptimal, however." . That was not enough info for me to continue the coding. Also, he said it was suboptimal, so I wonder if there is a correct/optimal way?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know the best way to pool predictions. I also think at this stage your question is not a programming one. You first need to decide what it is you want to accomplish and then what appropriate method to accomplish this. https://stats.stackexchange.com would be more appropriate for these discussions. Once you know what you want, then there may be programming questions. (ps I *think* this may be relevant to the missing links: https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr)

Comment: on "majority voting or averaging"  -- I'd thing averaging the predictions over the imputed datasets is clear but I hadn't heard of majority voting ; first website I hit was https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/wics.1362 may be relevant??

Comment: Perhaps for many it is clear how to just average the predictions over the imputed datasets, but not for me unfortunately. I am fairly new at R. For RF I am interested in feature importance and classification.  Could you perhaps help me get started on how to do that with my example in the original post? Note: In fact my data has around a 100 predictors instead of 6.  So I need to use coding without me having to type out all features haha. Thx for the link, but not really relevant, it only talks about the theoryand regular formulas, but there is zero code in that paper

Comment: For the average I may proceed as (pseudo code):1. impute datasets, say 5, 
2. loop through the 5 complete datasets making predictions (where you get the probability of an event) 3. average the predicted probabilities of each predicted observation over the 5 predictions.But really I would want to do some reading to find how this is normally done. Might be worth considering: train and test datasets. (I also remember a paper form around 5-10 years
ago which looked at building up prediction models using imputation & bootstrapping. I think from the medical domain. Might be worth doing a search.

Comment: ... I **think** this is the paper I was thinking of *The search for stable prognostic models in multiple imputed data sets: Vergouw*

Comment: Thanks  , but yeah again there is no code. I would like a guide where both theory is explained and examples+code are shown like StefvanBuuren does here: https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/ch-introduction.html

Comment: some code: if you use the loop from the cross-validated link answer. Uyou can average the predictions wit h `rowMeans(res)` or take the maximum `apply(m, 1, max)` or whichever method you feel (and can defend) is appropraite. And to avoid typing all predictors in see `?formula` i.e. use `y ~ .`

Comment: Thanks! Ill try it out this weekend. Yeah I know of the  y ~ ., , thanks